# macOS system events for network status in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, network-programming, systemevent

is there any system event which I can use in my program to detect a network change on macOS? I would like to call a function if the network state change, without having a lookup every x seconds in my program. Currently I'm using 'scheduledTimer' to make a lookup...

Is there a better solution for that?

Comment: What's a "network change" exactly? A change of WiFi network? A new network interface plugged in? A change in a network connection's DNS servers?

Comment: I would like to know if the device is connected to ethernet or wi-fi or nothing. Every time this state change (user plugged in the ethernet or turned of the wi-fi), the application must do some tasks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41590562/1187415. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15535571/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910121/1187415

Comment: You have to be even more specific. Are you particularly concerned about connecting/disconnecting to the internet? What happens if a user who's connected to a working, internet-reachable WiFi connection, and then plugs in an ethernet connection to an intranet. Do you care about that?

Comment: I just want to be informed if the user connect/disconnect a network. Then I would do the check if the user is in the company intranet in my attached function. I noticed that macOS always prefer a ethernet connection, so in the case that the user has also wi-fi enabled it would use the ethernet connection. and if this one is a intranet connection my function can do the rest...

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with the [`NWPathMonitor` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor). Using it, we can have a function called each time the state of the network changes (i.e., every time an interface connects or disconnects).

```swift
/**
 * A small program which watches for network changes on macOS without using a
 * polling system.
 *
 * Compile this with: `swiftc ./net-monitor.swift`
 */

import Network

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
  // inspect the `path` variable here for more information
  print("\(path)")
}

monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "net-monitor"))
dispatchMain()
```

Compiling and running that will emit lines that look like:

```
satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi
satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns
...
```

You can use the fields on the `path` object to detect the currently available interfaces, and check their connectivity and features (ethernet vs wifi, etc).